# What's the difference between a quarter and a district?

Tags: meaning, differences, speech

All I want to know about these words is their meaning difference and how they are used in sentences...
(If you can give me examples it would be great :))

Comment: "District" is fairly generic.  "Quarter" would only be used if it fit the local jargon.

Comment: Since 'quarter' is rarely used in 'BrE' for UK urban areas, it might be best to specify a perhaps 'AmE'. And attempts at research need to be shown.

Comment: I can't think of a US English usage of _quarter_ other than for the _French Quarter_ in New Orleans. _Quartier_ is frequently used to describe a neighborhood in French (_Quartier Latin_ in Paris, for example), and of course, there's a lot of French influence in New Orleans. Interestingly, the local French name for the French Quarter doesn't include the word _quartier_; it's the _Vieux Carré_. But the word _Quarter_ must have come from somewhere. My guess is that the New Orleans _Quarter_ is a big exception, related to French. Otherwise, US English does not really use _quarter_ in this context.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is both very easy and very hard.  To the extent that there are differences they are very subtle.

1. *District*. As in Pittsburgh’s *Strip District*, a strip of wholesale and specialist stores along the Allegheny River, with an diverse population
2. *Quarter* Like the *Latin Quarter (Quartier Latin)* on the left bank of the Seine, known for its intellectual and literary interest, close as it is to the University of the Sorbonne and the School of Fine Art (*Beaux Arts)*
3. *Neighbourhood* applies to any relatively self-contained portion of a town or city, usually with housing rather than blocks of flats (at least in the UK).
4. *Village* as in Greenwhich Village in New York, very artsy and, in its day, alternative culture.
5. *Town*. as in *Camden Town* in London, which was once just a town in the traditional sense before being absorbed into London, but now more associated with young people and families, outdoor markets and antiques.  It could have been called ‘Camden Village’.  Camden is also a huge London borough and could easily be described as a ‘district, but not really a neighbourhood.

I am afraid that travel is the only way to become confident in your use of these overlapping concepts.  But what can be said about your two words is that the word *district*, unlike the word *quarter*, can be used as an official or administrative subdivision of a city or even large town.  ‘*Quarter* is more unofficial (though you can find it on maps because it designates an area tha is know to be interesting and fun to visit.

Comment: In other words, a district is whatever is called 'district' and a quarter is whatever is called 'quarter'; there is no sharp criterion that would allow one to confidently say which of these words is the most apt for something, prior to finding out how people in fact refer to it. It should, however, also be noted that, as @Hot Licks pointed our above, *district* is a safer term to use if one is not familiar with the local terminology; *quarter* should be used only for what is known as a quarter.

Comment: @jsw29 Yes, and I think I made the distinction in my last paragraph.

Comment: In the United States, we also have Congressional districts, each of which elects a member of the U.S. House of Representatives.  Districts are based on population and reconfigured every ten years.

Comment: Also, central business district and secondary business district are standard terms. So is “school district.”

Comment: @Xanne Yes, that is a good example i had not thought of..